# Is it possible to pass groups to B2C from federated AD to Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I have an application running on B2C as part of customer deployment we federate with the customers AD so they can log in with their own corporate identity.

We then create matching groups in the B2C to control behaviors in the app.

We have a request that a customer wants to create the groups in their AD and then pass it across so that they can manage their users and access in one place.

I can see how I can add the claims I want when setting up a user flow but I cant see any option for groups.  Is it possible to do or do i have to query the external AD   (matching the way I query for groups in the B2C directory)

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to achieve this directly. But I still wonder why you need this. As Azure AD is for 2B scenario and all user groups are organization groups, why a 2C product needs organization groups? BTW, B2C has a feature to pass through the federated IdP access token inside the B2C token:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-custom

Comment: I should have been a bit more clear the application we run is deployed on a VM which is deployed to the customers subscription.

When we started building it we used B2C as we were not sure if we were going to host the app ourselves or deploy on their subscriptions.

As we are deploying to their subscription our customers can federate their AD so their users have single sign on.  But they still need to have groups in the B2C directory against the B2C created accounts.

Im wondering if we can pass the groups accross from the AD and then expose these via the B2C token like any other claim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While technically possible, I still have question for the benefit of doing this.
I will try to briefly describe how this would technically work. If not clear - I will have to summ-it on Github. This is only possible using custom policy. So you have to follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile

1. Edit the Menifest of the application registration in federated AAD. There you have to indicate that you require group membership claim:

   ```
   "groupMembershipClaims": "All",
   ```
2. Extend the claims schema in your custom policy extensions by adding a new claim:

```html
    <ClaimsSchema>
       <ClaimType Id="idpGroupMemberships">
        <DisplayName>Group Memberships in the IdP</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>This is read only for the user</UserHelpText>
       </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
```

3. Later in the technical profile, copy the incoming groups claim into your outputclaims:

```html
<OutputClaims>
   ...
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="idpGroupMemberships" PartnerClaimType="groups" />
</OutputClaims>
```

4. Finally, you have to include that new claim in your relying party policy:

```html
 <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SuSiLocalFbStaykovNet" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
...
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="idpGroupMemberships" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Using this approach you will get the Groups as GUIDs (these will be the objec IDs of the groups in federated AAD). If you want to get the Groups as names and not GUIDs, it is only partially supported and more complicated. Check out this doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes

Comment: Thanks alot, i was hoping to avoid a custom policy but will try this out

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer but some insight why this might be useful.

> While technically possible, I still have question for the benefit of doing this.

I have a smaller organization and a public facing B2C offer and a management UI that handles the customer requests. Some sensitive data is on an internal SQL server and we have for historical reasons and some elder software an on-premise AD. I have now running AAD B2B with hybrid connection and SQL via hybrid connection. Customers running on B2C. Because it's technically just one app, it's also just one login --> ADB2C with a social IDP pointing to AADB2B, that internally is backed by the on-premise AAD.

That all works very well and is exactly what we need. I came here with the same question as the OP to forward the security group information to the token to handle some access restrictions in the management UI.

Hence, for me the scenario makes absolutely sense. Just my 2 cent.